# Image disappears on div grow?

Tags: jquery

I have a div that grows on hover. Works great! However, I have an image that breaks the boundaries of the div, and when the div grows that image disappears? It reappears once the animation is complete, but clearly this isn't acceptable.

Why is this?

You can see it here: http://dev.mediaslave.ca/emerald/1/index.php

When you mouseover the bar on the bottom, the little triangle image disappears!

Here is the JQuery:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$(".main_menu").hover(
//on mouseover
function() {
  $(this).animate({
    height: '+=50' //adds 250px
    }, 'slow' //sets animation speed to slow
  );
},
//on mouseout
function() {
  $(this).animate ({
    height: '-=50px' //substracts 250px
    }, 'slow'
  );
}
 );

});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wZveg/

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that. I didn't post anything in the code because I didn't think it was the code causing the issue. I was thinking along the line that its an odd bug that happens on animate or something. I will add the code though above!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some way the animate() method add `overflow:hidden` on the class div `main_menu` and your img is positioned outside the height of the container then is hided. That property is setted only when the animation is runing. Try with this on the CSS:

```
.main_menu {    
  overflow:visible !important;
}
```

Check the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wZveg/1/)**

Comment: Danko is correct, it looks like the jQuery .Animate() function clips content that has 'overflowed' outside of the main area whilst it runs through the animation. (See http://api.jquery.com/animate/ - notes section)

Comment: You're right! That fixed it. Odd that it would decide to hide the image though; I've never seen it hide things like that before.

Comment: @JeffMonk the method use that to prevent multiple issues animating width and heights .. specially from `0` to another value.

Answer (score 3):

```
overflow:visible !important;
```

add it to .main_menu class :)

Answer (score 0):

I hate answers like this, but have you considered using css3 transitions? the code that you've written to do your hover state maintenance doesn't do what you think it does.  Jquery animate has some pretty tricky ways of doing time-based dom manipulation, whereas css transforms will accomplish exactly what you want with little fuss.

Additionally it gets javascript out of a page that is using it only to do presentation management (which is entirely the domain of CSS)

give this a shot:

```
.main_menu {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #000;
    padding: 6px 0;
    text-align: right;
    height:40px;
    transition:height 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:height 1s ease;
    -o-transition:height 1s ease;
}

.main_menu:hover{
    height: 90px;
}
```

Comment: fair enough, I'm trying to be helpful

Comment: I appreciate the help Lostinplace!

I thought about transitions, but I am worried about cross browser problems, especially on phones. This is intended to be a salestool, so it will see a lot of mobile use. 

That said I am still quite a Noob at all this stuff, so maybe its a good way to go?

Comment: As you can see in the above example, unsupported browsers will just yield an unsmooth transition.  I personally prefer this to crowding your css with important! directives